# there is an error on line 5 on image.can anyone please tell me why its showing error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
 home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(
              image: Image.asset('images/fawad.jpg'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as follow,

```
Image(image: AssetImage("images/michael.jpg"),),
```

"image" property expects an ImageProvider. While Image.asset is not an ImageProvider.

So you should provide a widget like AssetImage, FileImage, MemoryImage and NetworkImage Providers which suits best.

Comment: thanks.can u please tell me that where to use child and where not.i mean when we want to write text we write child:Text ,but when we use Container or Expanded etc,we donot wrap with child?why???

Comment: Container can have only one direct child. While, Rows and Columns are used to adjust child widgets horizontally and vertically respectively. Expanded can be used as a direct children of Rows or Columns. You cannot use it anywhere. Expanded is generally used to fill out the maximum possible space available for a child.

Comment: Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/michael.jpg'));
image.asset working fine in expanded but not in Image class
Image(image: Image.asset("images/michael.jpg"),)
why??

Comment: Expanded(child: Image.asset("'image-path")) here, expanded expects an Image Widget which Image.asset. So it is supported. While, Image(image: Image.asset("image-path")). So, here image expects an ImageProvider widget and if you will pass an Image widget then it will not work. You can not pass anything to anywhere. Can't you differentiate between "child" property of Expanded widget and "image" property Image widget? They both are different and they both expect different kind of behaviours. It's like you are passing an integer value to the function which expects a String value. I hope this helps

Comment: thanks man!much appreciation!!
i am new to flutter and its a little bit confusing.
if u know any link that will clear the flutter widget concept then please provide me.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets This is the list of all the widgets. Don't push too hard on yourself. Just start reading and trying them one by one and it  will help you to reach to your goal.